# Patent Status and Sale history

Tags: us3915038

In reference to the patent: [US3915038](https://www.google.com/patents/US3915038)

This patent belonged to my grandfather, who suffered from mental illness and tragically took his own life in 1973.  I have heard numerous stories from my relatives about what happened with this patent, but unfortunately they did not have the resources available to them to track the actual chain of events that they believe lead to the sale of this item, as well as others that my grandpa may have patented.  Do you know where I might be able to locate any information relating to this sale?